# Adding a negative value with a comma in it

Tags: php, html

I'm cycling through an array and adding up a figure.

I have a value of `-1,400` in my array. All other values work (i.e. if it is all positive and if it doesn't have a `,` in it), but for some reason the following code interprets the `-1,400` as `"-1"`.

```
$totregcat = 0;
while($v=mysql_fetch_array($listreg)) {
    print $v['amount']."-";
    $totregcat = $v['amount']+$totregcat; 
    print $totregcat."<br/>;
    $regtagid = $v['tagid'];
}
```

When I print `"$v['amount']"` I get the right figure, but the adding of it to the variable does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `(float) str_replace(",", "", $v['amount'])+$totregcat`. That should remove the comma and cast the result as a float.

Comment: I would use `(float)` instead of `(int)` since he's dealing with "amounts" and by the naming of the variables, and format of the values, I'm pretty sure he's dealing with currency, if he casts to int, he'll be losing cents.